# How to refactor similar foreach loops to follow DRY approach

Tags: php, foreach

If you have foreach loops of multiple arrays, and you need to run one of them inside another - Is it possible to refactor the following code to only have one loop to stop duplicating code:

```
<?php

$apples = array(
    'red',
);

$bananas = array(
    'yellow',
);

foreach ( $apples => $apple ) {
    echo '<div class="apple">' . $apple . '</div>';
}

foreach ( $bananas => $banana ) {
    echo '<div class="banana">';
    echo $banana;
    echo '<div class="child">';
        foreach ( $apples => $apple ) {
            echo '<div class="apple">' . $apple . '</div>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

/*
 output: 
 <div class="apple">red</div>
 <div class="banana">
   yellow
    <div class="child">
        <div class="apple">red</div>
    </div>
 </div>
 */
```

This code logic that is duplicate is the one that outputs the `<div class="apple">red</div>`:

```
foreach ( $apples => $apple ) {
    echo '<div class="apple">' . $apple . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Put the duplicated code in a function and call it from both places.

Comment: `foreach ( $apples => $apple )` isn't valid PHP syntax. Surely you mean `foreach ( $apples as $apple )`

Comment: So is your output right? You're just looking to refactor the code?

Comment: What makes an apple a "child" of a banana? And _why_ does it need to happen in this order - why is this not the other way around, and the banana is a child of an apple? Maybe there _was_ a way to write this so that expresses the inherent logic of this construct much better - but for that we would need to know, what the actual logic _is_ here to begin with. The given example does a poor job of actually explaining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's much improvement without being given better context, but using a function for generating the list should help reduce duplicate code.

```
<?php

$apples = array(
    'red',
);

$bananas = array(
    'yellow',
);


function getFruitListHTML(array $fruitList, string $class, string $child = ''): string {
    $out = '';
    foreach ( $fruitList as $fruitItem ) {
        $out .= "<div class=\"$class\">";
        $out .= $fruitItem;
        $out .= $child;
        $out .= '</div>';
    }
    return $out;
}

$applesHTML = getFruitListHTML($apples, 'apple');
echo $applesHTML;
echo getFruitListHTML($bananas, 'banana', "<div class=\"child\">$applesHTML</div>");
```

Comment: Not only does this consolidate the duplicate code, it also allows the presentation to be the last thing that happens.  Win-win.  Even better would be to make the function recurseable so that it manages the child's html too.  But this is definitely the right idea